# PHP not working after upgrading to OS Mojave

Tags: apache, php, mojave, mamp

When i try to open localhost it gives me 403 error message like this "You don't have permission to access / on this server."
I have tried changing the permission but nothing happens. It worked fine with High Sierra but after update its not working.I am using the pre installed apache and not using third party apps like xampp[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem - it's based on mod_userdir exclusion after updating to Mac OS X Mojave. There are a few steps to repair that:

1. Load the module `mod_userdir` in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`
2. At the end of the `httpd.conf` make sure to load `httpd-userdir.conf`
3. In httpd-userdir.conf include a local file in `/etc/apache2/users/<username>.conf`
4. Put a directory section into that file, containing the rules for the directory where your webserver files are located:

   ```
   <Directory "/Users/<myusername>/Sites/">
       AllowOverride All
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```

This should set you up.

Comment: This worked .. however when I access localhost .. it gives me index of all the files does not load the website.

Comment: Do you have an index.html in the directory?

Comment: On macos the config file is at /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf

Comment: On /etc/apache2/httpd.conf search for "#LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so". Remove "#", then restart Apache. Hope that helps...

Answer (score 5):

The Mojave update (or re-install) overwrites the apache directory but left my old configs with the `~previous` suffix left.

I did edit a lot of *previous* files in my apache path `/private/etc/apache2`. These files were renamed to like `httpd.conf~previous` and a new `httpd.conf` has taken place.

I **just renamed files**, restart my apache and everything is working like before now. It wasn't every previous file, as i knew i did not edited all of them.

In my case also the `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf~previous` had to get back in place

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after I updated to **Big Sur**.

In my case the configuration files from the apache2 folder were supposedly 'incompatible with the recent macOS upgrade'.

Because of that Apple moved my `httpd.conf` and `httpd-vhosts.conf` to

```
/Users/Shared/Relocated Items
```

I just had to copy them over to the old location and everything worked again.

Answer (score 1):

Apache
The new macOS Mojave comes with Apache pre-installed. All we have to do is switch it on.

Open Terminal using macOS Spotlight or go to /Applications/Utilities and open Terminal.

To check the version of Apache installed run the following command in the Terminal.

Check that :
https://www.dyclassroom.com/howto-mac/how-to-install-apache-mysql-php-on-macos-mojave-10-14

Comment: This definitely helped me. Please add the actual command to run in Terminal to your answer.