# Fix permissions in Apache

Tags: macos, mojave, permission, apache

I'm trying to use the built-in Apache server in MacOS mojave.

In my browser, accessing http://localhost/~myusername/mypage.html (in case of user dir) or http://localhost/mypage.html (in case of default dir) both throw the same error in the browser:

```
Forbidden You don't have permission to access /mysite/ on this server.
```

I' trying to make both the default dir `/Library/WebServer/Documents` and an user dir `~/myusername/Sites`works.
I tried 2 solutions:

1. I tried to add a vhost in `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName localhost
   DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
2. I tried to add a `myusername.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/users` with the following content

   ```
   <Directory "/Users/myusername/Sites/">
   Options Indexes MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   </Directory>
   ```

Is there a guide to understanding permission errors on Mojave using Apple shipped Apache?

**EDIT: It looks like the [accepted answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338099/php-not-working-after-upgrading-to-os-mojave) solved the reading permission for me.**
From the answer:

> 1. Load the module `mod_userdir` in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`
> 2. At the end of the `httpd.conf` make sure to load `httpd-userdir.conf`
> 3. In `httpd-userdir.conf` include a local file in `/etc/apache2/users/<username>.conf`
> 4. Put a directory section into that file, containing the rules for the directory where your webserver files are located:
>
>    ```
>      <Directory "/Users/<myusername>/Sites/">
>          AllowOverride All
>          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
>          Require all granted
>      </Directory>
>    ```

**Writing access to files is still a problem**: Apache cannot edit a file if the ownership is mine (the admin user). I'm still wondering if there is a proper way to fix the permission without messing up each directory permissions every new project.

This is the script I'm using for testing write permission:

```
<?php
    echo 'Current script owner: ' . get_current_user();
    echo 'Current user:' . system('whoami');
    $current = file_get_contents('people.txt');
    $current .= "John Smith\n";
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

I get the error:

> Warning: file_put_contents(people.txt): failed to open stream:
>   Permission denied

Comment: What action yields the permission error?

Comment: all the actions from the browser: when I try to access `http://localhost/~myusername/mypage.html` (in case of user dir) or  `http://localhost/mypage.html` (in case of default dir)

Answer (score 1):

Apache in macOS Server runs as the `_www` user. Try granting this user write access to the directory with an ACL entry.

```
chmod +a "_www allow list,search,add_file,add_subdirectory,delete_child,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" "/Users/<user>/Sites"
```

Comment: nop, it doesn't solve..I still get `Permission denied` when I try to write in a file