# Location of "/usr/local/var/www" on M1 Mac (Big Sur)?

Tags: macos, big-sur, apple-silicon, apache

I'm trying to set up `Apache` which includes putting this path into `httpd-vhosts.conf` file:

```
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/var/www"
```

but I can't find the folder. The only path that seems to resemble the folder is `/private/var` but it doesn't contain a `www` folder/file. Where is it located?

Comment: You are free to set `DocumentRoot` to whatever value you want - the only restriction is that the user that runs the Apache web server must be able to  read the directory contents. If you don't want to create `/usr/local/var/www`, use a different directory, for example `/Library/WebServer/Documents` (this is the directory the Apache web server included with macOS uses, see `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`).

Comment: Many [guides for Apache on macOS](https://dyclassroom.com/howto-mac/how-to-install-apache-mysql-php-on-macos-mojave-10-14) do prefer `~/Sites` and `/Library/WebServer/Documents` so use caution if you prefer `/usr/local` and [everyone needs to watch for Previous Items when updates run](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/443619/5472). Avoiding [ACL permissions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/365364/5472 ) might be a good reason for local based storage and posix permissions.

Answer (score 2):

As an admin user, run

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/var/www
sudo chown _www:_www /usr/local/var/www
```

User/group `_www` is the default setting in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`. If you have a different user/group for your webserver, you need to adapt the second command accordingly.

---

To make this work with whatever path is defined in `httpd.conf`, run

```
docroot=$(sed -E -n '/^DocumentRoot/{
s|.*\"(.*)\"|\1|p
q
}' /path/to/httpd.conf)
sudo mkdir -p "$docroot"
sudo chown _www:_www "$docroot"
```

(the first four lines are one command, but macOS `sed` expects function lists to be separated by newlines.)